# How do I use console.table but to stderr?

Tags: node.js, console, console.log

I find that `console.table()` is good, in a few cases, for error messages. However, it doesn't print to stderr. How do I print console.table to stderr in Node.js?

Comment: Use `console.error()`

Comment: @Shubh, it doesn't table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Node.js, one can instantiate a custom Console instance with a different writable stream than stdout using the [console module](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html), e.g.:

```
const { Console } = require("console");
const console = new Console(process.stderr);
```

This would have any method that typically uses stdout, including `table()`, use stderr instead.

Comment: Works great, especially since I can have 2 console instances in the same prorgam.